# Loading entities GKScene and SKReferenceNodes via SpriteKitBuilder automation

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, gameplay-kit

It seems that GKScene does not "magically" load entities that come from SKReferenceNodes into its entities array, I am wondering if anybody knows how to get this working without adding custom extensions or classes.

There is no code to show, the idea is to be using the SpriteKitBuilder's automation to get this working.

Here is what I have

> Character.sks
>   -->SKSpriteNode with Components added to it.

--

> GameScene.sks
>   --> SKReferenceNode -> Character.sks

Now if I add the SKSpriteNode directly to the GameScene, the entities get filled in, it is only when using the reference node that it becomes empty.

Comment: Seems somebody on apple dev has a similar problem, so this may be a bug, and not just me doing something wrong here. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/72298